# How to stop MediaPlayerElement playing audio after navigating to another frame?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

MediaPlayerElement is playing audio after navigating to another Frame. If I again navigate to this Frame, I can hear two instances of the audio, One is from the audio of the currently playing video and another is from the last time when I navigated to this Frame. How can I stop MediaPlayerElement after navigating to another Frame?

**For Reference:**

Entire Code of my XAML Part of the Frame

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/MediaPlayerDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <MediaPlayerElement  Name="YoutubePlayer" MaxWidth="640" MaxHeight="360" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True">
        <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
            <video:CustomMediaTransportControls x:Name="CustomMediaControl" IsSkipBackwardButtonVisible="True" IsSkipForwardButtonVisible="True" IsSkipBackwardEnabled="True" IsSkipForwardEnabled="True" IsFullWindowButtonVisible="True" IsFullWindowEnabled="True" QualityChanged="CustomMediaControl_QualityChangedAsync"/>
        </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
    </MediaPlayerElement>
</Grid>
```

Entire Code of my C# Part of the Frame

```
public sealed partial class VideosPage : Page
{

public VideosPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
    YoutubePlayer.MediaPlayer.Dispose();
}

public async Task setVideoSourceAsync(YouTubeQuality videoQuality)
{

    try
    {
        var youtubeUrl = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync("QTYVJhy04rs", YouTubeQuality.Quality144P, videoQuality);
        YoutubePlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(youtubeUrl.Uri);
        YoutubePlayer.AutoPlay = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //await setVideoSourceAsync();
    }
}

private async void Page_LoadedAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsViewModeSupported(ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay))
    {
        CustomMediaControl.IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible = true;
    }
    await setVideoSourceAsync(YouTubeQuality.Quality360P);
}

private async void CustomMediaControl_QualityChangedAsync(object sender, QualityChangedEventArgs e)
{
    await setVideoSourceAsync(e.NewQuality);
}
}
```

Comment: can you provide some code? including the xaml declaration.

Comment: @Hannes Sure, I will edit the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you want to happen when you navigate away from your Page you could for example dispose the MediaPlayer by adding this method to your codebehind in the page the MediaPlayer is in:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{  
    base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,() =>
    {
        YoutubePlayer?.MediaPlayer.Dispose();
    });
}
```

You may also want to just stop it and continue when navigated back to the Page therefore you should probably override the `void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)` method.

Comment: Program crashes with a UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION error.  AnimeZeno.exe!AnimeZeno.App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__5_1(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 53

Comment: Thanks, It works. Can I know the reason for the error? and Can I know what `await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,() =>
    {
        YoutubePlayer?.MediaPlayer.Dispose();
    });` this means?

Comment: UIElements can only be updated from within the UI-Thread otherwise an error will occur. It appears that OnNavigatingFrom is being called from a non ui thread. To change the UI from another thread you use this peace of code. Because it is asynchronous you can use the await keyword to wait for it to finish. Methodes containing await need to be marked async as well. (Maybe you can do this without the await and async keywords but im not sure, because than maybe the Page has already changed when accessing the YoutubePlayer.)

Comment: Thanks, It was helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this issue as well. The accepted answer leads to an unhandled exception even with the await. Here is what the override handler from the sample code provided here should look like.

```
protected async override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{  
    base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
    YoutubePlayer.Source = null;
}
```